# Failed to execute goal org.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project (target 11)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku, deployment

I tried to deploy the simplest app from spring.io guides
[Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

But I have some troubles.. 
What I did:

1. Created project. (from spring.io tutorial)
2. Downloaded heroku CLI
3. Opened terminal in IntellijIdea
   3.1 git init
   3.2 git add .
   3.3 git commit -m "fd"
   3.4 git remote add heroke 'url'
   3.5 git push heroku master
4. After the last command I have this error:

```
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  12.608 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-23T18:20:18Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project milliapp: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to deploymilliapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/deploymilliapp.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/deploymilliapp.git'
```

Answer (score 14):

Solved.
Deleted this part of code

```
<properties>
<java.version>11</java.version>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to "tell" Heroku, that you want to run you app on Java 11. To do so add the **system.properties** file to your project (I did it in the main directory) and put the following line inside it:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I created system.properties file in the location where pom.xml resides. Then added java.runtime.version=11 and it worked.

Refer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support  for additional information.

Answer (score 4):

If using intelij,

1. make system.properties file and put it in the root directory (where pom.xml is)
2. in this file, write the appropriate versions e.g.
   java.runtime.version=11
   maven.version=3.6.2
3. deploy again
   During this step, read the log file to see JDk 12 is installed by heroku

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml file, comment below line in properties tag.

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Second solution:

1. Downgrade app to java 8
2. Use `maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1` with that configuration:

```
   <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <testSource>8</testSource>
                    <testTarget>8</testTarget>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are telling maven to use JDK 11 to build your app but you have your java_home set to a different version. Change your java_home env variable to your java 11 installation and it would build it in 11.

Answer (score 0):

delete this properties from your pom.xml

`<properties> <java.version>11</java.version> </properties>`

and rebuild your project !